# Equal Height Column Working Only On Desktop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have code in my bootstrap 5 website like this

```
<div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-md-6 mt-3 mt-md-0">
        <a href="post/good-morning-status-shayari-68346" class="h-100"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500/" class="img-fluid blog-img lzy_img" alt="Good Morning Status Shayari" width="100%" height="100%">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mt-3 mt-md-0">
        <div class="bg-dark text-white blog_content d-flex flex-column bg-black h-100 text-center pt-3 pb-3 px-3 mx-3">
            <h5>સપનાઓ ચા જેવા કડક હોવા </h5>
            <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1 justify-content-center align-items-center mb-0">
                <div class="">
                    <p class="">સપનાઓ ચા જેવા<br> કડક હોવા જોઈએ સાહેબ,<br> જે રાતની ઊંઘ છીનવી લે !!<br> શુભ સવાર</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="time d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center align-items-end mt-auto border-top pt-3">
                <div class="left text-start">
                    <h6 class="mb-0"><a class="link-bold" href="https://stag.example.com/gu/category/gujarati-good-morning-status-shayari">શુભ સવાર સ્ટેટસ શાયરી</a></h6>
                    <p class="mb-0"><small>6 days ago</small></p>
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Its working fine and output like this in desktop:
[image]

But in Mobile doesn't have equal height and it's looking like:

[image]

Basically I want same height column as image in mobile device too but its not working. I am using bootstrap 5.2.

I have added code in [codeplay](https://www.codeply.com/p/aJFCYpgrMV%5D) for text.

Let me know if someone here can help me for solve the puzzle.

Comment: @yunesMohammady what is board box?

Comment: Put the border box in box sizing mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can easily be accomplished by using the [aspect ratio helper classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/helpers/ratio/#aspect-ratios). Just apply `.ratio.ratio-1x1` to the inner wrapper within the `.col-md-6`s.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row mt-3">
  <div class="col-md-6 mt-3 mt-md-0">
    <a href="post/good-morning-status-shayari-68346" class="h-100 ratio ratio-1x1"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500/" class="img-fluid blog-img lzy_img" alt="Good Morning Status Shayari" width="100%" height="100%">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 mt-3 mt-md-0">
    <div class="bg-dark text-white blog_content d-flex flex-column bg-black h-100 text-center pt-3 pb-3 px-3 mx-3 ratio ratio-1x1">
      <h5>સપનાઓ ચા જેવા કડક હોવા </h5>
      <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1 justify-content-center align-items-center mb-0">
        <div class="">
          <p class="">સપનાઓ ચા જેવા<br> કડક હોવા જોઈએ સાહેબ,<br> જે રાતની ઊંઘ છીનવી લે !!<br> શુભ સવાર</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="time d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center align-items-end mt-auto border-top pt-3">
        <div class="left text-start">
          <h6 class="mb-0"><a class="link-bold" href="https://stag.example.com/gu/category/gujarati-good-morning-status-shayari">શુભ સવાર સ્ટેટસ શાયરી</a></h6>
          <p class="mb-0"><small>6 days ago</small></p>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.col-md-6 img {height: 100%;}
.col-md-6 { text-align: center; height:500px; }
```